# Rails migration failed with an error syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I am very new to rails an d I have this in my model

```
PreGit::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :microposts
  resources :users

  match '/help',    to:'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to:'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to:'static_pages#contact'

  root_path => '/'
  root_url => 'http://localhost:3000/'

end
```

But when running `bundle exec rake db:migrate` I get that :

```
syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
  match '/help',    to:'static_pages#help'
                    ^
```

Someone could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is not a Rails issue but a Ruby version issue.

In Ruby 1.8.x the hash syntax was

```
:to => static_pages#help'
```

but Ruby 1.9.x supports

```
to:'static_pages#help'
```

so probably you are trying to run an app developed under Ruby 1.9.x under your Ruby 1.8.x

Try running the same app under Ruby 1.9.x

If you are using rvm then try this

`rvm list` #will list all your ruby versions

If you have ruby 1.9.x installed

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.x
```

Comment: In fact, I realized it worked only when deleting these two lines root_path => '/'
  root_url => 'http://localhost:3000/ but when I add these I get syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end
  root_url => 'http://localhost:3000/'
             ^
Do you have an idea ?

Comment: normally in routes.rb you define the root url as root :to => '<controller>#action', Ex: root :to => '/' and hope u r using rails 3.x, I'm not sure why u have two root urls.

Comment: Hi again @sameera207, I added this root :to => '/', and I got that : .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:174:in `default_controller_and_action': controller name should not start with a slash (ArgumentError)

Comment: Hi , change the root_to => 'static_pages#help' and see how it goes, the syntax is <controller>#<action> :)